# Trying to build Xperience17-caf ROM with Clo rom build tag: How to solve HALs and FCM incompatibility error?

Tags: android, build, android-manifest

`(Clo rom build)Rom build fails because of manifest.xml and framework_compatibility_matrix.xml

Hey there, I'm trying to build Xperience17-caf for my device(apollo/mi10t) and having this issue near build completion:

```
`
`The following HALs in device manifest are not declared in FCM <= level 5:
  android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.3::IBiometricsFingerprint/default
  android.hardware.drm@1.4::ICryptoFactory/clearkey
  android.hardware.drm@1.4::IDrmFactory/clearkey
  android.hardware.usb@1.3::IUsb/default
  android.hardware.wifi.hostapd.IHostapd/default (@1)
  android.hardware.wifi.supplicant.ISupplicant/default (@1)
  android.hardware.wifi@1.6::IWifi/default
  vendor.qti.hardware.wifi.supplicant.ISupplicantVendor/default (@1)
INCOMPATIBLE

    stderr:ERROR: files are incompatible: Device manifest and framework compatibility matrix are incompatible: HALs incompatible. Matrix level = 5. Manifest >
android.hardware.graphics.composer:
    required: @2.1-4::IComposer/default
    provided:
android.hardware.graphics.mapper:
    required:
        @2.1::IMapper/default OR
        @3.0::IMapper/default OR
        @4.0::IMapper/default
    provided:

The following instances are in the device manifest but not specified in framework compatibility matrix:
    vendor.qti.hardware.wifi.supplicant.ISupplicantVendor/default (@1)``
```

I've only built a few aosp roms and never encountered this so kinda clueless as to what I'm supposed to do, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I can supply the full log if needed.

trees I'm using:
https://github.com/gmw-project/device_xiaomi_apollo/tree/13-clo
https://github.com/gmw-project/device_xiaomi_sm8250-common(same for vendor, common vendor)
kernel:
https://github.com/LineageOS/android_kernel_xiaomi_sm8250

also tried taking the manifests from another common tree but to no avail.`